# Ajax Reload iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I reload iframe using jquery?

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js" > </script>


<script type="text/javascript">
//Reload Iframe Function    
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <iframe name="f1" id = "f1" src="http://www.google.com.pk/search?q=usa+current+time&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&client=firefox-a&rlz=1R1GGLL_en" width=500px height=250px>
    </iframe>

<button onClick="abc()"> Reload </button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 13):

Based on your comment to Haim's post, what you want could be simplified as:

```
$('#reload').click(function() {
    $('#f1').attr('src', $('#f1').attr('src'));
    return false;
});
```

Or

```
$('#reload').click(function() {
    $('#f1')[0].contentWindow.location.reload(true);
    return false;
});
```

But perhaps his answers better suits your needs.

**UPDATE:**

I put together a working example using the method I provided above. I have an `<iframe>` in one page that shows another page that prints the time.

**The `<iframe>` HTML** (time.html):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    The time is now <span id="time"></span>.

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#time').html((new Date()).toString());
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

**And the parent page HTML** (test.html):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <iframe id="frame" src="file:///D:/Users/Cory/Desktop/time.html" width="500" height="250"></iframe>

    <button id="reload">Refresh</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#reload').click(function() {
                $('#frame').attr('src', $('#frame').attr('src'));
                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

This works just fine for me in Firefox 3.6 and IE 7.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I've tried your code but unfortunately its not working.

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#reload').click(function() {
    $('#f1')[0].contentWindow.location.reload(true);
    return false;
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe name="f1" id = "f1" src="http://www.google.com.pk/search?q=usa+current+time&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&client=firefox-a&rlz=1R1GGLL_en" width=500px height=250px> </iframe>
<button id="reload" > Reload </button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: You might want to post large comments like these as updates to your original post. Please see my update on my answer for a working example.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#reload").click(function() {
            jQuery.each($("iframe"), function() {
                $(this).attr({
                    src: $(this).attr("src")
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
```

This will loop through **each** iFrame every time you click on a link with a class of reloadAds and set the source of the iFrame to itself

Comment: Here is my code:

<body>
 <iframe name="f1" id = "f1" src="http://www.google.com.pk/search?q=usa+current+time&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&client=firefox-a&rlz=1R1GGLL_en" width=500px height=250px>

 </iframe>
<button id="reload" onClick="reloadFrame('f1')"> Reload </button>
</body>